# Giving recursive definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I need to give the recursive function of $3n^2$. 
I'm pretty sure the base case needs to be $3 \cdot 0^2 = 0$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=3n^2$, then
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=3n^2-3(n-1)^2=6n-3$$
Therefore,
$$a_n=6n-3+a_{n-1}$$
$$a_0=3\cdot 0^2=0$$
is the recursive relation.

Comment: Is this the same as a recursive definition? My text book talks about first creating a base case and then a second part that eventually will use the base case. Maybe that doesn't apply to this problem though.

Comment: @Josh Yes you need a base case, since otherwise the recursive relation will keep going down to $-\infty$. You correctly stated in your question that $a_0=0$.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I'm a little confused here. So the entire definition would be my base case and then your relation?

Comment: @Josh Indeed, both parts are necessary for a full recursive formula. I updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Great, I understand now, thanks.